# I get an error when I try to import a get request from a controller module to my main app. (Type-error : Cannot read proper 'get' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, controllers

This is my `index.js` file in my `./home` directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var control = require('./controllers/todoController');
var app = express();

//set up template engine

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//static files
app.use(express.static('./public'));

//fire controllers

control();

//listen to port
app.listen(3000);
console.log('You are listening to port 3000');
```

This is my `todoController.js` file in my `./home/controllers` directory:

```
module.exports =function(app){
  app.get('/quiz', function(req, res){
  res.render('quiz');
});
};
```

The error that is shown is:

```
TypeError : cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the router module of expressjs

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token('token');
    if(!token)
    {
        res.render('error', {
            'message': "You must indicate a Token"
        });
    }
    
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, just import it on your app.js main file :

```
app.use('/', tokenHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give your `app` to `controller` as parameter

Try this in your `index.js` file

```
//fire controllers

control(app);
```